# Four week supply or four-week supply

Tags: hyphenation

Should four week supply be hyphenated as four-week supply?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, hyphenated (although non-hyphenated is increasingly common). As "four week" acts as an adjective (which is why *week* is singular even though preceded by a plural number), it should be hyphenated to avoid any ambiguity on how to parse "week". An alternative construction would be *four weeks' supply*, where no hyphen should be used.

Answer (score 3):

A four-week supply. We may express quantities, sizes, etc, with a compound adjective, consisting of a quantity and a unit of measurement (in singular form), before a noun. It is hyphenated: a five-mile walk, a ten-ton truck, a three-hour wait. If the quantity has more than one word, all are hyphenated too, thus a two-thousand-page book, a five-hundred-thousand-dollar prize.

[Hyphens](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Or perhaps you may say "Four weeks' worth of supply" Bypassing the need for hyphens but I doubt this is what you wanted.

Comment: It should be *supplies*, not *supply*, in your version.